# simple rx code silently fails in windows forms only during debugging in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive

Feels like bugs and problems are attracted to me lately! =P

So I finally took some time off today to explore a little Rx.

Heres what I did:

[image]

Here's the only piece of running code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       var txtc = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(textBox1, "TextChanged")
                 .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                 .SubscribeOnDispatcher();//**also tried .SubscribeOn(this)
       var t = from x in txtc select textBox1.Text;
       t.Subscribe(x => listBox1.Items.Add(x));
 }
```

Now, when run Debug (F5) I click the Button, all good, I then type something, poof! The form just silently dies!!

**If I run without debugging, the application runs flawlessly!**

Note: I removed the code from the Form.Load event because of the known bug with VS not breaking on exceptions in that event on **Win7x64** (and yes thats my machine)

This is what the debug output looks like:

> > The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1438) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> >
> > The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x155c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> >
> > 'RxWinForms.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded '\RxWinForms\bin\Debug\RxWinForms.exe', Symbols loaded.
> >
> > A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
> >
> > The program '[5228] RxWinForms.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> >
> > The program '[5228] RxWinForms.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that either the Throttling is happening on the current dispatcher or that you switch back on to the current dispatcher through ObserveOn (not SubscribeOn) before you try and change the UI (I believe that by default Throttling is done on the TaskPool).

So both of the solutions below work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtc = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(textBox1, "TextChanged")
       .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
       .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher);

    var t = from x in txtc 
            select textBox1.Text;

    t.Subscribe(x => listBox1.Items.Add(x));
}
```

and

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtc = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(textBox1, "TextChanged")
      .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), Scheduler.Dispatcher)

   var t = from x in txtc 
           select textBox1.Text;

   t.Subscribe(x => listBox1.Items.Add(x));
}
```

Comment: +1 Excellent, I thought I hit an issue! Tell me, what does `SubscribeOnDispatcher()` do? Seems a wee bit annoying since a lot of examples use `SubscribeOnDispatcher()` .

Comment: @giddy In the unlikely case that an observable source (which is anything that implements IObservable) blocks during a Subscribe() call, you can use SubscribeOn to make sure it doesn't.

Comment: thanks=) I see... so what does `SubscribeOnDispatcher()` really do? DO I make a call to both `SubscribeOnDispatcher()` and `SubscribeOn` Or was my original code partially wrong? (Since I picked that up from a silver-light example)

Comment: @giddy SubscribeOn (and SubscribeOnDispatcher, which is just a call to SubscribeOn passing in Scheduler.Dispatcher) wraps your Subscribe() call in scheduler.Schedule(() => originalSource.Subscribe()). It is used in the rare case that an observable blocks during the call to Subscribe

Answer (score 2):

James is correct. However, it is recommended that you use the `IScheduler` overload of methods (like `Throttle`, rather than using the default overload and then using `ObserveOn` (which will cause it to jump to the task pool and then back to the dispatcher).